# Generate a random subset of the powerset directly

Tags: r, set, combinations, powerset

It is easy to generate a random subset of the powerset if we are able to compute all elements of the powerset first and then randomly draw a sample out of it:

```
set.seed(12)
x = 1:4
n.samples = 3

library(HapEstXXR)
power.set = HapEstXXR::powerset(x)
sample(power.set, size = n.samples, replace = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 3 4
```

However, if the length of `x` is large, there will be too many elements for the powerset. I am therefore looking for a way to directly compute a random subset.
One possibility is to first draw a "random length" and then draw random subset of `x` using the "random length":

```
len = sample(1:length(x), size = n.samples, replace = TRUE)
len
# [1] 2 1 1

lapply(len, function(l) sort(sample(x, size = l)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1
```

This, however, generates duplicates. Of course, I could now remove the duplicates and repeat the previous sampling using a `while` loop until I end up with `n.samples` non-duplicate random subsets of the powerset:

```
drawSubsetOfPowerset = function(x, n) {
  ret = list()
  while(length(ret) < n) {
    # draw a "random length" with some meaningful prob to reduce number of loops
    len = sample(0:n, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = choose(n, 0:n)/2^n)
    # draw random subset of x using the "random length" and sort it to better identify duplicates
    random.subset = lapply(len, function(l) sort(sample(x, size = l)))
    # remove duplicates
    ret = unique(c(ret, random.subset))
  }
  return(ret)
}

drawSubsetOfPowerset(x, n.samples)
```

Of course, I could now try to optimize several components of my `drawSubsetOfPowerset` function, e.g. (1) trying to avoid the copying of the object `ret` in each iteration of the loop, (2) using a faster sort, (3) using a faster way to remove duplicates of the list, ...

My question is: Is there maybe a different way (which is more efficient) of doing this?

Comment: In your example above, do you want to remain with item 1 and 2 since three is a duplicate of 2 or do you wantto just remain with 1?

Comment: There is an error in your code. What does `m` equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using binary representation?  This way we can generate a random subset of integers from the length of the total number of power sets given by `2^length(v)`. From there we can make use of `intToBits` along with indexing to guarantee we generate random unique subsets of the power set in an ordered fashion.

```
randomSubsetOfPowSet <- function(v, n, mySeed) {
    set.seed(mySeed)
    lapply(sample(2^length(v), n) - 1, function(x) v[intToBits(x) > 0])
}
```

Taking `x = 1:4`, `n.samples = 5`, and a random seed of 42, we have:

```
randomSubsetOfPowSet(1:4, 5, 42)
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 2 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

### Explanation

- What does binary representation have to do with power sets?

It turns out that given a set, we can find all subsets by turning to bits (yes, 0s and 1s). By viewing the elements in a subset as `on` elements in the original set and the elements not in that subset as `off`, we now have a very tangible way of thinking about how to generate each subset. Observe:

```
       Original set: {a,  b,  c,  d}
                      |   |   |   |
                      V   V   V   V        b & d 
Existence in subset: 1/0 1/0 1/0 1/0       are on
                                            / \
                                           /   \
                                          |     |
                                          V     V
Example subset: {b, d} gets mapped to {0, 1, 0, 1}
                                       |  \   \  \_______
                                       |   |   \__       \
                                       |   |___   \____   \____
                                       |       |       |       |
                                       V       V       V       V
Thus, {b, d} is mapped to the integer  0*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^3 = 10
```

This is now a problem of combinations of bits of length *n*. If you map this out for every subset of `A = {a, b, c, d}`, you will obtain `0:15`. Therefore, to obtain a random subset of the power set of `A`, we simply generate a random subset of `0:15` and map each integer to a subset of `A`. How might we do this?

> `sample` comes to mind.

Now, it is very easy to go the other way as well (i.e. from an integer to a subset of our original set)

Observe:

```
Given the integer 10 and set A given above (i.e. {a, b, c, d}) we have:

10 in bits is -->> {0, 1, 0, 1}

Which indices are greater than 0?

Answer: 2 and 4
```

> Taking the 2nd the 4th element of our set gives: {b, d} *et Voila!*